# Storing data from Matlab GUI components

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am creating GUI in Matlab. I am using 4 sliders, 4 static texts and axes for plotting. I ran into a problem with storing value from sliders.

I set sliders for default value. When I move one slider, everything plots as supposed. When I  move with another slider, the value from first slider restores to default and value from second set as supposed.

For example I use slider that defines radius of a Cycloid. Then i call for function that set value for slider and then I call for function that plots results.

It looks like this :

```
% setting slider

slider(1)=uicontrol(container_1,'Style','slider','Min',0.1,'Max',10,'Value',1,'Tag','r');

% setting slider value

set(slider(:),'callback',{@obj.setValue});

% function to set value and store it as obj.r = value 

function    setValue(obj,handle,~)
            obj.(handle.Tag)=handle.Value;
            myPlot(obj);
end
```

This is just a cut piece from whole code. Whole code is in my pasterbin:

https://pastebin.com/XqYYAxRP

Sum up:

What I need is that Value of slider will not restore to default, but will stay after moving with slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a value class (MATLAB's default) rather than a `handle` class. With the value class, any modifications to the object (in your callback) are not going to be present in other copies of the object since they are independent copies therefore your callback will seem to have no effect. When you use a `handle` class instead, assignment will create a new *reference* to the same object and changes will persist across all references.

```
classdef Cykloida < handle
```

See a detailed discussion of the two types of classes in [the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to work perfect now.